# How to change format of sql table in Tarantool

Tags: sql, tarantool

I want to add nullable column to sql table, but changing table format leads to an error:

```
box.execute([[
    CREATE TABLE test(
        "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        "name" TEXT NOT NULL
    )
]])

f = box.space.TEST:format()

table.insert(f, {type='string', name='description', is_nullable=true})

box.space.TEST:format(f)
```

```
error: 'Can''t modify space ''TEST'': exact_field_count must be either 0 or >= formatted
    field count'
```

So is there any way to change format of sql table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment (Tarantool 2.4 beta) there is [an open issue](https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/1994) about that. The source of the problem is that tables created via SQL DDL contain non-null [field_count](https://www.tarantool.io/ru/doc/2.3/reference/reference_lua/box_space/#lua-data.space_object.field_count) property in metadata, which forbids saving larger tuples into the space.

However, if you specified `field_count` when creating the space or used SQL DDL for creating it, and decided to add a tuple/column, here is a workaround for setting the `field_count` value to 0:

```lua
tarantool> box.space._space:update(box.space.YOUR_SPACE.id, {{'=',5,0}})
```

After that, you will be able to change the space format and insert larger tuples. Replace `YOUR_SPACE` with the actual name of your space. In case of a space created via SQL DDL this name will be the SQL table name in capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

An update: In the latest stable Tarantool version (2.7.2) it is now possible to add a column with ALTER, for example `box.execute([[ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN third INTEGER;]])`